# Spring-damper in series

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I have a spring-damper system like so:

[image: spring-damper in series]

When $x_1$ is the length of the spring and $x_2$ is the length of the damper.
The forces are given by:
$$ \\ x=x_1+x_2\\F_d=-\sigma\ \frac{dx}{dt}\ , F_k=-k(x_1-x_0)$$
Which means that the damping force depends on the velocity of the mass.
From Newton we get:
$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}= -k(x_1-x_0)-\sigma\ \frac{dx}{dt}\ $$
Which can't be solved unless there is another relationship between $x_1$ and $x$.
Am I missing something? Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Your equation of motion is incorrect. The forces are identical, not additive. You can show this by drawing a free-body diagram of each component.

Answer (score 2):

This is the FBD

[image]

From here you can obtain the equation of motion, you should get second order differential equation plus first order differential equation.

Edit

$$m_1\,\ddot x_2=F_\sigma$$

and put dummy mass between the spring and the damper

$$m_d\,\ddot x_1=F_k-F_\sigma$$

with $~m_d=0~$ and

$$F_k-F_\sigma=0\quad,F_\sigma=\sigma\,(\dot x_1-\dot x_2)\quad,
F_k=-k\,x_1\quad,
\quad \Rightarrow\\
-k\,x_1-\sigma\,(\dot x_1-\dot x_2)=0
 $$
hence
$$\sigma\,\dot x_1=-k\,x_1+\sigma\,\dot x_2\tag 1$$

and

$$m\,\ddot x_2=\sigma\,(\dot x_1-\dot x_2)=-k\,x_1\tag 2$$

equation (1) and (2) are the EOM's

Comment: That is exactly what I got. Thank you!

Comment: @OfirShukrun you got spring damper parallel. I will write you the equations