# Finding the equation of motion from diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, spring

Friction, and initial values of functions can be ignored. $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ stands for the horizontal displacement and $f(t)$ is the force working on mass $M$. $K_1, K_2$ are the coefficient for spring and $D$ is the damping coefficient of dashpot.

From this diagram, I would like to find its **equation of motion** with respect to $f(t)$ and $x(t)$ in order to get its transfer function, yet, I am really bad at physics.

[image]

Actually, I have tried to comprehend and follow this post [Spring-damper in series](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/676924/371905) , and below is the procedure that I attempted to solve this,

$$
  \begin{align*}
     & M\ddot{x}(t) = -K_2x(t) + F_{K1} + f(t) \\
     & M_d\ddot{x}(t) = F_D - F_{K1} = 0 \quad(M_d = 0) \\
     & F_D = -D\dot{y}(t), \space F_{K1} = K_1[x(t) - y(t)] \\
     & D\dot{y}(t) = K_1[x(t) - y(t)] \\
     & M\ddot{x}(t) = -K_2x(t) - F_{K1} +f(t)  = -K_2x(t) + D\dot{y}(t) + f(t)
  \end{align*}
$$

However, from the equations above, I did not see the possibility that I can replace all y with x, what I have missed?

Below are the updated equations and transfer function based on the suggestion by Eli:

**Equation of Motion**
$$
    \begin{align*}
        & M\ddot{x}(t) = f(t) - K_2x(t) - F_{K1} \\
        & M_d\ddot{y}(t) = F_D - F_{K1} = 0, \quad (M_d = 0) \\
        & F_D - F_{K1} = -D\dot{y}(t) - K_1[x(t) - y(t)] = 0  \\
        & M\ddot{x}(t) = f(t) - K_2x(t) + D\dot{y}(t)  \\
        & M\ddot{x}(t) + K_2x(t) - D\dot{y}(t) = f(t)
    \end{align*}
$$

**Transfer Function:**
$$
    \begin{align*}
        & -DsY(s) = K_1[X(s) - Y(s)], \space Y(s) = \dfrac{K_1}{K_1-Ds}X(s) \\
        & X(s)\{Ms^2 +K_2+\dfrac{K_1Ds}{K_1-Ds}\} = F(s) \\
        & G(s) = \dfrac{X(s)}{F(s)} = \dfrac{K_1-Ds}{(K_1-Ds)(Ms^2+K_2)+K_1Ds}
    \end{align*}
$$

Comment: Why you want to replace all y to x ?

Comment: @Eli Hi. When I get the equation, I will transfer it to the Laplace transform form, and I am asked to take $F(s)$ as input and $X(s)$ as output, that is why I would like to replace all y to x.

Comment: @ Sonamu, transfer also $~\dot  y~$ to $~s\,Y(S)~$ check the sign of the forces it is not correct

Comment: Ok, I will check the signs, and see if I can replace them.